# Scheduled vs actual dates & times on a table

Tags: user-expectation, web-app, tables, dates, time

I'm designing a "Deliveries" page for a B2B web app. Users can see their deliveries on a table and filter, see the details of each delivery, and export.

The columns of the table are:

- Delivery ID
- Date
- Time
- Order nº
- From
- To
- Status

Deliveres can have multiple Status:

- Pending
- Confirmed
- Ongoing
- Delivered

For Pending, Confirmed and Ongoing deliveries the "Date" and "Time" are scheduled, while for Delivered ones the date and time is exact (because it happened).

My questions is:

- What is the best way to convey this information on the table?

I've considered creating different columns for scheduled dates and times and actual dates and times, but I don't have much space on the table and seems like a bit overwhelming. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the status field right after the ID (or before the date and time field), it will provide the right context for the date and time values.

By putting it right at the end, the user will scan the date and time, then read the status and have to go back and work out if it is a scheduled or the actual value.

If you really want to make it scannable, you can use a combination of colours and symbols to denote the difference between scheduled and actual date/time values, but it would introduce more complexity in the visual design than necessary. You can also put some information in a tooltip to show what the status mean so that the user will know how to interpret the date and time fields as well.